# Three CheckBoxes in a settings screen only letting the user click one at a time

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have three CheckBoxes in a settings screen, but I only want the user to be allowed to click one. How can I make it so when the user clicks on one it unblocks the other. Here is my code in my main activity that connects the checkboxes to their sound value.

```
            standardSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fanpost);

            alternateSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alternate_fan);

            whiteSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.white_noise);

            SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

            boolean alternate = getPrefs.getBoolean("alternate", false);
            boolean white = getPrefs.getBoolean("white", false);
            boolean standard = getPrefs.getBoolean("standard",false);

            if (blade.getAnimation() == null) {


                // no animation, start it
                if (alternate == true) {
                    alternateSound.start();
                    alternateSound.setLooping(true);
                    blade.startAnimation(animRotate);
                    if (blade.getAnimation() == null) {
                        alternateSound.stop();
                        alternateSound.prepareAsync();
                    }


                } else if (white == true) {
                    whiteSound.start();
                    whiteSound.setLooping(true);
                    blade.startAnimation(animRotate);
                    if (blade.getAnimation() == null) {
                        whiteSound.stop();
                        whiteSound.prepareAsync();
                    }

                } else if (standardFan == true) {
                    standardSound.start();
                    standardSound.setLooping(true);
                    blade.startAnimation(animRotate);
                    if (blade.getAnimation() == null) {
                        standardSound.stop();
                        standardSound.prepareAsync();
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Radio buttons are meant to do that.

Comment: where is the checkbox codes part?

Comment: The sharedPreference booleans are the checkboxes

Comment: Well how would you use radio buttons for this sort of thing

Comment: Do you want the user to only select one box or give access to other choices from the first choice?

Comment: The user should only be able to select one checkbox

Comment: So using radio buttons is the solution, get a look at this : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html. If you really want checkbox just verify other boxes with isChecked and so on.

Comment: I am using checkboxes instead of radio buttons because you can not make a radio group in a preference screen, and could you elaborate on how I could use checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `ListPreference` in your preference xml file, here is a tutorial :
[ListPreference](http://rominirani.com/android-preferences-tutorial/)

Comment: This won't work. I cannot set an onClickListener to checkboxes in a separate preference screen, and you never defined what isChecked is

Comment: isChecked is a method of CheckBox class. What do you mean by a separate preference screen?

Comment: This code is in my main activity which is fetching the value from my preference screen.

Comment: Well i guess I could do this code in my preference class, but how would I reference the checkboxes.

Comment: Okay  i get what you want to do you just have to use ListPreference.